# Is the same code with different exception handling considered as repeated code?

Tags: java, coding-style

As refactoring my code, I realize some of code is repeated except the exception handling of them. I am wondering whether these codes are considered to be repeated to refactor, if so, how?

Specific sample:
E.g I have two methods.

```
void fun1() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        handle1();
    }
}

void fun2() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        handle2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to provide a more complete example that illustrates why you'd need to wrap exception handling in two separate (and otherwise identical) functions? To me, it seems like it's generally an indication of bad design that can be fixed somewhere else, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: I know it is never recommend to catch general exception. However, the problem I am facing could be. I am catching the same exception type, but in fun1() and fun2(). I do have different handling mechanism

Comment: So you would (theoretically) handle the same Exception type in different ways? E.g. a RuntimeException would be handled differently in the fun1 use-case as opposed to the fun2 use-case?

Comment: Say I am writing some tests. For the same code in different test, I plan to have different logs/data-chart/error-logs, so basically catching the same exception type, but handle it differently

Comment: This seems like the sort of problem that can be solved with polymorphism - just overload your ````handle```` method, right?

Comment: hmm. seem to be a way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not do like this:

```
try {
        foo();
    } catch (Exception1 ex) {
        handle1();
    } catch (Exception2 ex) {
        handle2();
    }
```

Comment: I know it is never recommend to catch general exception. However, the problem I am facing could be. I am catching the same exception type, but in fun1() and fun2(). I do have different handling mechanism

Comment: Yes that is fine if you want to catch the same exception but handle it differently depending on what method is called you could leave it how you have it...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all, catching all `Exception`s is a bad habit, you shouldn't really do it, only catch the ones that you expect.

I woudln't consider it repeated, because in one case you may expect one exception in another you may expect a different one. That's another reason to be specific in you catch clauses. Then, you can also use a multicatch statement, like this:

```
void fun() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (MyFirstException ex) {
        handle1();
    } catch (MySecondException ex) {
        handle2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some repetition here, but not much. You could consolidate the code somewhat better, by passing the expected error-handling function into a helper method as an argument. Note that this would be much more verbose prior to Java 8.

```
void fun1() {
    funHelper(this::handle1);
}

void fun2() {
    funHelper(this::handle2);
}

void funHelper(Runnable errorHandler) {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        errorHandler.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the way to do this in java8?

Comment: @user3393757: Disclaimer: I haven't actually used Java 8, so my syntax may have some errors.

Comment: @user3393757: The way I posted here is theoretically how it should work in Java 8. In versions prior to 8, you'd have to create an anonymous implementation of `Runnable` whose `run` method calls `handle1` and `handle2`. In Java 8, you should be able to just pass a reference to the method, and the compiler figures out the rest.

Comment: @user3393757: I just fixed at least one syntax mistake. You need to use the `::` operator when passing method references.